# Python detect a python script's name in the list of processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, psutil

I know I can use `psutil` to get a list of running processes' names like this

```
import psutil

for i in psutil.pids():
    print(psutil.Process(i).name())
```

However, If i run a python script with python, **psutil** only will show me that I have an instance of **python** running.

So, my question is - if I run a python script:

```
python script_name
```

is it possible to detect `script_name` by **psutil**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at `psutil.Process(i).cmdline()` [docs](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.cmdline).  Your example would return

```
['python', 'script_name']
```

Comment: The latest psutil docs are [here](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#functions), as the above link is long outdated.

Answer (score 2):

The [psutil](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process) documentation states that the cmdline() method returns the command line of the process. If the command line is `python script_name`, the second word will be the actual script name. To get this information I'd change `psutil.Process(i).name()` to `psutil.Process(i).cmdline()`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to read the script name from the command line arguments:

```
import psutil
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        if "python" in proc.name():
            print(proc.cmdline[1])
    except:
          pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that cmdline is a function and requires a ()
print(proc.cmdline()[1])

Comment: What? There is no `cmdline` in the question.